# Choosing Balls: $3$ Green, $5$ Blue and $4$ red

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So this is a question someone asked me about and that is ostensibly a basic combinatorics question, though I'm getting conflicting answers:

Say we have a bag with $3$ green, $5$ blue and $4$ red balls.  What is the probability of choosing three balls of the same color?

As near as I can tell, the best way to solve this is the following:

How many ways can we choose $3$ of the same color? Well, we can choose all 3 green balls (this is $1$ way) we could choose $3$ blue balls ($5 \choose 3$ ways to do this), or we could choose $3$ red balls (4 ways). Dividing by $12\choose 3$ total ways to do this, we get something like .0681... as our probability.

On the other hand, we could say the probability is P(drawing 3 green)+P(drawing 3 blue)+P(drawing 3 red) which to me looks something like $$\frac{3\times 2\times 1}{12^3}+\frac{5\times 4\times 3}{12^3}+\frac{4\times 3\times 2}{12^3}\approx.0521...$$

So what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Not $12^3$ in your last displayed equation, but $12\cdot11\cdot10$. You are not replacing the balls after selection.

Comment: Oho! Thankyou! What a mistake! If you'd like to post this as the answer, I will choose it.  If not, I'll make it an answer, just so I can have some closure!

Comment: @David, Oops, my apologies. I did not notice your comment till now.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is correct.  Your second approach is almost right, but the denominator is off.

Let's take the probability that you draw 3 red balls. Yes, the first ball is red w.p. $4/12$. But once you draw a single red ball, the number of *red* balls, as well as the *total number of balls* goes down by 1. So the probability that second ball is also red (conditioned on the first ball being red) is $3/11$, not $3/12$. Similarly, for the third ball, this probability is $2/11$.

So you end up with
$$
\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10}.
$$
As a mental check, note that this is the same as
$$
\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}.
$$
Proceeding likewise, the final answer is
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10} = \frac{\binom53 + \binom43 + \binom33}{\binom{12}{3}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the density function for the hypergeometric distribution for this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution  Briefly, for two colors (say, white and black) dhyper(a,b,c,d) is the probability of drawing a white balls when there are b white balls in the urn, c black balls, and you are making d draws without replacement.

Your second approach is correct (once you fix the denominator) and boils down to:

dhyper(3,3,9,3)+dhyper(3,5,7,3)+dhyper(3,4,8,3)

As you are only making three draws, you don't have to worry about overlap.